# Getting data from php using ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax request and get the data from a PHP file; that is, a single row based on a where condition. I don't know how to extract the PHP array in JavaScript.

My Ajax code:

```
function loadData(Sno)
{
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to 
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/getgreetings.php?loadsno=" + Sno,             
    dataType: "json",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(data){          
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert (response.Greet_Name);
    }
    });
}
```

My PHP code:

```
require('db.php');      
    $loadsno = $_GET['loadsno'];    
    $query = "SELECT * from Greetings where greetsno=".$loadsno ;

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
     $data = array();
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) 
     {
       $data[] = $row;
     }

    echo (json_encode($data));
```

Comment: "not working" is the best description of the problem you could give?

Comment: With `dataType: "json",` it's not `html` expected to be returned. It's `json` expected to be returned, aha.

Comment: thats just a old comment. just skip it off

Comment: Then if json __already__ returned - then why do you call `parseJSON`, huh?

Comment: Also use developers console and useful `console.log(data)`

Comment: Use console.log(data); before this line: response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: console.log displays as [Object]

Comment: And console.log(response).

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` That will give you the clearest picture of the returned data. Or you can look in the response to the ajax request in the Network tab.

Comment: since your PHP returns an array, you'll probably have something like `[{ Greet_Name: "srinivasan", AnotherField: "x"}, { Greet_Name: "y", AnotherField: "z"}]`. Therefore you need to loop through the response object as if it's a JS array, using a `for (i=0; i<response.length;i++)`, and then you can do `response[i].Greet_Name` to get each of the returned names.